# ASP.NET Get Only Users with Roles using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and SqlRoleProvider

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, authorization

I've inherited a site that uses an `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` for authentication and a `SqlRoleProvider` for authorization. The authentication is going against our company's LDAP server, so there's a couple hundred users. However, the site I'm creating will only use about 60 or 70 of those users.
Is there a way to easily get just the users of my site (ie the Users with Roles in my `SqlRoleProvider`)? Or do I have to get all (couple hundred) Users, then loop through and see if their Roles match any of the Roles in my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is curious,
I ended up using a nested `foreach`; looping through all the roles in my site, then looping through `Roles.GetUsersInRole(role)` and adding the user to a List<> (after first checking to make sure they weren't already in it).